# Passport.js: Sign in with Github and return email address

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have built a node.js web app that uses `passport.js` with the `passport-github` strategy. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
var passport = require('passport');
var GithubStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy;
passport.use(new GithubStrategy({
    clientID: "foo",
    clientSecret: "bar",
    callbackURL: "baz",
    profileFields: ['email']
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    return done(null, profile);
}));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
app.use(session({
    secret: 'this is a secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    html = JSON.stringify(req.user, null, 4);
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'My Home Page',
        html: html
    });
});
//Login
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', {
        title: 'Login to Chordscribble!'
    });
});
//Logout
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
// GitHub
app.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github', {
    scope: ['user:email']
}));
app.get('/auth/github/callback', passport.authenticate('github', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Everything is working fine except that I am getting a return value of `null` for the email address. My first question is, is there a way to guarantee that I will always get an email address? And, my second question is, if not, what how should I store this in a database without an email address? Possibly by assigning my own user id field and using their Github ID? Is the GitHub ID always going to be unique?

Answer (score 3):

#### If you are using `passport-github`Strategy:

You should pass `scope: 'user:email'`, rather than passing `profileFields: ['email']` which is passed in the Facebook Passport Strategy.

As @mherzig said you should consider looking for the [scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) of the OAuth you are using, and Github accepts `user:email` for passing the **emails**

So, you should be using this for `passport-github` strategy:

```
  new GitHubStrategy(
    {
      clientID: ...,
      clientSecret: ...,
      callbackURL: ...,
      scope: 'user:email',
    },
    ...
  );
```

[Source](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github/issues/15#issuecomment-262108779)

---

#### If you are using `passport-github2` Strategy:

You should pass scope as an array, in [github-passport2](https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github) Strategy.

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
   clientID: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
   clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
   scope: ['user:email'],
   callbackURL: process.env.GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL
},
...
);
```

[Source](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github/issues/15#issuecomment-287837508)

Answer (score 0):

Most authentication services have the concept of scopes--you can only get certain personal info if the user agrees to let you have it. For GitHub, see https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes.

Basically, the scope(s) that you want access to must be passed along with the authentication request. I'm not sure how that happens with passport-github, but maybe there is another way to do it that sends the scope you are looking for.

If you really don't need the email address and you just wanted it for uniqueness, then don't ask for it--users will see what scope(s) you are requesting and if you ask for too many they may choose to not let your app authenticate. The user ID will be unique across GitHub, but may not be unique across all identity providers (if you eventually use more than just GitHub) so if you need a unique ID you should somehow combine/hash the provider *and* the user ID so you it is unique across all providers.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub users can configure in their GitHub profile (Personal settings/Profile) a "Public email".

If they don't have selected a public email address, you won't receive any user email from GitHub.

The GitHub ID will be (probably) unique and permanent. But I suggest you to double check GitHub policies.